# What does the phrase "falling far" mean?

Tags: meaning

**[SOURCE](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/againstthecurrent/closerfaster.html)**

What does this phrase mean:

> "We're falling far tonight"

..especially "falling far"? I really can't find anywhere what that means.

Comment: Could you please add some more context to your question?

Comment: "When it gets darker we're falling far tonight" ,this is pretty much all

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to tell us what you did not understand about your English dictionary's definition of the verb _to fall_ and the adverb _far._ What English dictionary did you consult? This is a song lyric, but you should at least begin with understanding what the words mean outside of their "poetic" use here.

Answer (score 2):

The song you are referring to is a love song and the context of everything within the lyrics is about the love between 2 people.

The [definition of **fall** in this context](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fall) is

> 13. to pass into some physical, mental, or emotional condition:
>     *to fall asleep; to fall in love.*

So the phrase

> "We're falling far tonight"

means that that the extent of falling in love is great tonight

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without context.

Literally, "far" just means a long distance, so "falling far" is just falling a long distance.

"Fallen far" (used in the past tense) is sometimes used to describe a loss of prestige or reputation. That meaning is not generally used except in describing something which has already happened, but your passage might be playing on that.

There are also a few biblical references which might fit. The "fall of man" specifically refers to the loss of innocence in the Garden of Eden, and angels can "fall from grace." Either meaning could fit.